# SQL-Exception in listing

Tags: java, database, sqlexception

I'm programming a small application in Java, a very basic database containing (fictional) student data. It works quiet okay so far, but I've encountered a problem when trying to make a list containing the curriculum of the university the students are frequenting. I want to list every possible degree, all of which have 6 semesters, along with the courses that can be taken in every category, how many hours per week they take and so on. The first bit works, but I encounter a problem when trying to fill the different categories with their respective courses over each semester. Heres the code (things I deem relevant to the problem are enclosed with two stars):

```
@Override
public List<List<String>> getStudyingplan(Studies s) throws ApplicationException {
    List<List<String>> curriculum= new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    String currentCategory;

    String name = s.getName();
    String abb= s.getAbbreviation();
    String category;
    String categoryHeader= ("Mod E C P Cr");

    line.add("Course of studies\n" + name + " (" + abb+ ")");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        line.add(i + ". Semester");
    }
    line.add("");
    curriculum.add(line);
    line= new ArrayList();

    line.add("Category");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        line.add(categoryHeader);
    }
    line.add("Sum");
    curriculum.add(line);
    line= new ArrayList();

    //Connect to database:

    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(database);

        PreparedStatement giveCategories = con.prepareStatement("SELECT distinct k.* "
    + "FROM CATEGORY c, CURRICULUM cu, MODULE m "
    + "WHERE cu.SABB = ? AND cu.MABB = m.MABB AND m.KABB = c.KABB "
    + "ORDER BY c.INDEX");

        **PreparedStatement giveModule = con.prepareStatement("SELECT distinct m.*" + 
            "FROM MODULE m, STUDIES st, CURRICULUM c" + 
            "WHERE st.SKABB = ? AND c.SEM = ? "
            + "AND c.MABB = m.MABB AND m.KABB = ?");**

        giveCategories.setString(1, abb);
        **giveModule.setString(1, abb);**
        ResultSet categoriesGiven= giveCategories.executeQuery();

        while (categoriesGiven.next()) {
            categories.add(categoriesGiven.getString("NAME") + " (" + 
                    categoriesGiven.getString("KABB") + ")");
        }

        **for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            currentCategory = categories.get(i);
            line.add(currentCategory);
            giveModule.setString(3, currentCategory);
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            Integer seme = new Integer(j);
            seme++;
            giveModule.setString(2, seme.toString());
            ResultSet current Modules = giveModules.executeQuery();
            while (currentModules.next()) {
               zeile.add(currentModules.getString("MABB"));
            }
        }
        line.add("Sum");
        curriculum.add(line);
        line= new ArrayList();
    }**
        *A bunch of other stuff happens*

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("getStudyingPlan has encountered an error.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
   return curriculum;
}
```

The error I keep getting says:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "st" at line 1, column 73
```

so I'm assuming that there is an error in the `PreparedStatement` somewhere, but I can't seem to find it. Any help, even just a nudge, would be greatly appreciated while I'm trying to figure out the problem by myself.

Comment: You are missing a space after `CURRICULUM c`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query is running together, put a space after the `c`.

```
"FROM MODULE m, STUDIES st, CURRICULUM c" + 
"WHERE st.SKABB = ? AND c.SEM = ? "
```

Should become

```
"FROM MODULE m, STUDIES st, CURRICULUM c " + // Note space
"WHERE st.SKABB = ? AND c.SEM = ? "
```

Comment: Ah, you made this just as I commented on the question!

Comment: I feel dumb now. Solved. Thank you.

Comment: Don't feel dumb, it happens frequently and sometimes you just need another pair of eyes on it. Best of luck.

Comment: My best practice when concanating query strings is always end any line with a whitespace ;)